# A probability problem, with percentages.

Tags: probability, statistics

Could anyone help solving this problem?

When asking a  group of people about three books $A, B,C$ it was found that:
36% of them read book $A$ , 39% read book $B$ and 40% read book $C$. And 15% read $A$ and $B$, 9% read $C$ and $B$ and 11% read $A$ and $C$. And 5% read the three books $A$ and $B$ and $c$.

1- find the percentage of people who don't read any of the books.

2- find the percentage of people who read two books only.

3-  find the percentage of people who read one book only.

4- Assuming that the population is 500 persons, how many people read the book $A$ only?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: We have the following probabilities:
$P(A)=0.36$, $P(B)=0.39$ and $P(C)=0.4$

Comment: OK, that's a start.  So if $A$ is the event of reading book A, then what is the event $A'$?

Comment: Easiest way to solve these problems is to make a Venn diagram.

Comment: and $P(A\bigvee B\bigvee C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \bigwedge B)-P(A \bigwedge C)-P(C \bigwedge B)-P(A \bigwedge B \bigwedge C) =0.36+0.39+0.4-0.15-0.11-0.09-0.05=0.75$

Comment: @sososos  You should really put this in your post! It shows you are making some effort and it helps us see where you are getting stuck.

Comment: $P(A^')=1-0.36=0.64$

Comment: so percentage of people who don't read any of the books is:
$1-P(A \bigcup B \bigcup C)=1-0.75=0.25$

Comment: I am stuck in finding the probability laws which are useful in my previous problem

Comment: Check your signs, you have a sign flip there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start:

[image]

So you know that 5% read all three books.  The yellow highlighted area is the people who read A and B (and may or may not read book C), which you are told is 15%. So, how many people read book A and B, but not C? That would be 15%-5%=10%.  You can also use the formula:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C')$

So given that $P(A \cap B \cap C)=0.05$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0.15$, you can derive that $P(A \cap B \cap C')=0.15-0.05=0.10$

OK, so now do that for all other areas!

Comment: $P(A\bigcap \acute{B} \bigcap C)=0.11-0.05=0.06$ and $P(\acute{A}\bigcap B  \bigcap C)=0.09-0.05=0.04$

Comment: OK, good!  So fil in those percentages into the Venn diagram, and given that $P(A)=0.40$, compute the area that is inside $A$, but outside $B$ and $C$. .. So that would be $P(A \cap B' \cap C')$.  And then do the same for $B$ and $C$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Suppose A is the Red-yellow-pink cricle, and B is the Green (and neighbors) cricle, and C is Blue

the white region is $A\cap B\cap C = 5\%$

The Yellow and White together are $A\cap B = 9\%$
So the Yellow region is  $A\cap B = 9\% - 5\% = 4\%$

You have enough information to fill out all 8 regions.

If you want to take a more algebraic approach

you could say that the Grey region is $A'\cap B' \cap C'$

$(1 - A)\cap (1 - B)\cap(1 - C) = 1 - A - B - C + A\cap B +  A\cap C +  B\cap C - A\cap B \cap C = 1 -0.36-0.39-0.40+0.15+0.09+0.11-0.05$

Comment: $P(A\bigcap \acute{B}\bigcap \acute{C})=0.15$ and $P( \acute{A} \bigcap B \bigcap \acute{C})=0.2$ and $P(\acute{A}\bigcap \acute{B}\bigcap C)=0.25$

Comment: $P(A\bigcap \acute{B}\bigcap \acute{C})+P( \acute{A} \bigcap B \bigcap \acute{C})+P(\acute{A}\bigcap \acute{B}\bigcap C)=0.6$ is the percentage of people who read only one book, am I right?

Comment: $P(A\bigcap B \bigcap \acute{C})+P(A \bigcap \acute{B} \bigcap C)+P(\acute{A}\bigcap B\bigcap C)=0.1+0.06+0.04=0.2$ is the percentage of people who read two books, am I right?

Comment: That looks correct.

Comment: $P(A\bigcap \acute{B} \bigcap \acute{C})=0.15$ so we have $0.15*500=75$ persons read the book $A$ only. right? :)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PbWa.jpg)
1-  the percentage of people who don't read any of the books. 30%

2- find the percentage of people who read two books only. 35%

3- find the percentage of people who read one book only. 30%

4- Assuming that the population is 500 persons, how many people read the book A only? 5 persons